# Chaning matrix into matrix with only unique numbers R

Tags: r, matrix, jitter

How do i change a matrix into a matrix with only unique numbers

I tried this:

```
dataset <- as.matrix(iris[,1:4])

head(dataset)
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
[1,]          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
[2,]          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
[3,]          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
[4,]          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
[5,]          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
[6,]          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4

datasetUnique <- jitter(dataset,factor = 0.001)

head(datasetUnique)
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
[1,]     5.100001    3.499998     1.399999   0.2000009
[2,]     4.900000    2.999999     1.399999   0.2000016
[3,]     4.700001    3.199999     1.300000   0.1999983
[4,]     4.600001    3.100002     1.500001   0.1999988
[5,]     4.999999    3.599999     1.399998   0.1999989
[6,]     5.399999    3.900000     1.699999   0.3999981
```

But this not makes all numbers unique.
How do i achieve that?

Comment: They are probably unique, but they don't print as unique, because printing will truncate / round the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add more decimals, then they become unique.

```
options(digits=10)

dataset <- as.matrix(iris[,1:4])
datasetUnique <- jitter(dataset,factor = 0.001)

> head(datasetUnique)
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width
[1,]  5.099982209 3.500005068  1.399988968 0.2000082396
[2,]  4.900019249 2.999988556  1.399985779 0.2000159874
[3,]  4.699981033 3.199993951  1.300013794 0.1999958768
[4,]  4.600000369 3.099985655  1.499996616 0.1999957113
[5,]  5.000014609 3.599997256  1.400002512 0.1999995772
[6,]  5.399992065 3.900010935  1.700003428 0.3999821202
```

A second possibility is using non-random numbers to prevent "bad luck".

```
options(digits=10)

dataset          <- as.matrix(iris[,1:4])
increment_matrix <- matrix(seq( from = 0, to = 0.001, length.out =  ncol(dataset)* nrow(dataset) ) , ncol = ncol(dataset))
datasetUnique    <- dataset + increment_matrix
```

Comment: So in the datasetUnqiue every number will be unique, even if all initial numbers are the same and you have an extremely big matrix? matrix(rep(1,600),ncol = 4,nrow = 150) but then extremely big

Comment: Not necessarily. If your matrix is big enough some numbers will repeat. But in case you use 22 decimals and a factor of 0.001 the matrix must be extremly big. I am not sure what your aim is but if you want unique numbers you could simply check whether all numbers are unique and if not just roll the dice again. Or you specify an very small increment (first number + 0.0000001 second 0.0000002) to prevent unlucky random draws. I add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the cleanest way but you can use `sample` to get unique numbers and then divide it by a large number to create noise then add it onto you matrix i.e.

```
mat <- matrix( c(1,2,2,3) , nrow = 2)  
mat + sample.int(5000, nrow(mat) * ncol(mat)) / 5000000
```

Make sure to adjust the numbers as appropriate for your desired degree of accuracy